# ViewModel whose data is loaded by an async task

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I am just confused about the idea of ViewModel when you have data that is loaded asynchronously.

Here is an example of a ViewModel

```
public class UsersViewModel extends ViewModel {

     private List<User> userList;

     public List<User> getUserList() {
        if (userList == null) {
             usersList = loadUsers();
         }
         return userList;
     }

     private List<User> loadUsers() {
         // This is async task
     }
 }
```

Activity:

```
public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         UsersViewModel usersViewModel =
             ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UsersViewModel.class);

         showUsers(usersViewModel.getUserList());
     }
 }
```

This will show an empty list( or perhaps crash on null) since the asynctask has not been done. All the examples I saw online, were synchronouse blocking calls. But what about cases where it is an asynchronous call which will get the data from a server and update the UI as a result. How do we handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using live data. The ViewModel will return MutableLiveData and on your view, you will subscribe to any value changes.

You can also use data binding, then your data on view will automatically changes.

```
public class NameViewModel extends ViewModel {

    // Create a LiveData with a String
    private MutableLiveData<String> mCurrentName;

    public MutableLiveData<String> getCurrentName() {
      if (mCurrentName == null) {
        mCurrentName = new MutableLiveData<String>();
      }
      return mCurrentName;
    }

 // Rest of the ViewModel...
}
```

Then on your Activity:

```
public class NameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private NameViewModel mModel;

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Other code to setup the activity...

    // Get the ViewModel.
    mModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NameViewModel.class);


    // Create the observer which updates the UI.
    final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
            // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
            mNameTextView.setText(newName);
        }
    };

    // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
    mModel.getCurrentName().observe(this, nameObserver);
  }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: I see would I add an observer/observable to every UI field. say I have 10 textfields, then will there be 10 observer/ observable ?

Comment: As danypata suggested, would be nice you use databinding, then you would only need to reference on your view the properties! I hope that it will help you!

Answer (score 2):

As Felipe R. suggested in his answer, you can achieve it using LiveData, but I will say that you shouldn't stop there.

The real power of Android architecture components comes in when you use all of them combined.

- ViewModel -- will make your live a lot easier when you want to update the UI from background threads or other long running processes, since they are linked to the Activit/Fragment lifecycle but in an independent way, so no more NPE on views that are removed from window when your AsyncTask posts the result of a job.
- LiveData -- will help you to transmit data from ViewModel to the UI, not worrying about what thread returned the response. LiveData can be replaced with RxJava or Rx for Kotlin but I prefer it for UI Updates
- Data Binding -- will help you "auto-update" the UI when info is there, will also spare you from some NPE from time to time.

From these 3 components, I think ViewModel is the only one that is kind of pointless to be used by it's own. The other two can bring some advantages, but the full power comes in when you use all of them. 
You'll also have an awesome time writing tests for your implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the ellaboration. It is good to see the push for it